# unix network programming book code has bugs due to old OS, how to solve this or where to get new code ?

Tags: c, linux, unix, networking

I am trying to download and run the c code on Linux for

UNIX Network Programming, Volume 1, Second Edition: Networking APIs: Sockets and XTI, Prentice Hall, 1998, ISBN 0-13-490012-X. It is by W. Stevens Richard

```
 http://kohala.com/start/unpv12e/unpv12e.tar.gz
```

But, when I build the code, I got error:

```
  gcc -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -Wall   -c -o connect_nonb.o connect_nonb.c
  In file included from connect_nonb.c:1:
   unp.h:114: error: redefinition of âstruct in_pktinfoâ
   make: *** [connect_nonb.o] Error 1
```

I commented out struct in_pktinfo.  Then I got new errors:

```
   gcc -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -Wall   -c -o in_cksum.o in_cksum.c
   gcc -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -Wall   -c -o inet_ntop.o inet_ntop.c
   inet_ntop.c: In function âinet_ntopâ:
   inet_ntop.c:61: error: argument âsizeâ doesnât match prototype
   /usr/include/arpa/inet.h:67: error: prototype declaration
   make: *** [inet_ntop.o] Error 1
```

I do not want to debug for the whole 575 files one by one.

Where can I get new code without these errors ? the new version book has bug-free code ?

The old code is only for old OS.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you download the code and compile it on linux before voting down.

Comment: Perhaps the [source code](http://www.unpbook.com/src.html) from the [third edition](http://www.unpbook.com/) will work better.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: do you happen to know if the 3rd edition code works on, say, recent ubuntu distros - after maybe only adding the right include directory locations and such? The above probably happens as structures Stevens defines or uses have been replaced. Serious question: currently reading his TCO/IP classic, finding it brilliant (after all these years), and considering to buy the above in latest edition - which is still old.

Comment: @gnometorule: I haven't tested (or even looked at) any of the code from the book recently enough to be sure. Based on rather distant recollections, I'd guess more of it will work as-is, but there's probably still some that would need some work before it would compile (as you say, even the newest edition is just under 10 years old).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It's a shame as these are outstanding books (in my opinion).

Comment: Are there very good books about network programming on Linux ?

Comment: I think each .c file is one demo code for example. Try to read the book and do the sample one by one.

Comment: @user1002288: Richard Stevens Books are still the reference I choose for Linux networking.

Answer (score 11):

well, The [Author Richard Stevens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Richard_Stevens) passed away in 1999 and the Book is still the a very good reference. You can't say this about a lot of more than 10 year old technical references.

I just fetched the source from http://www.unpbook.com/unpv13e.tar.gz and followed the readme, which basically meant to run **./configure** and call **make** in the directories

```
/lib
/libfree
/intro
```

I fixed a single place (libfree/inet_ntop.c:60 and changed **size** to **socklen** ) and it compiled on my current Ubuntu. I didn't run it, but I trust that at least the most of it will work.

***Richard Stevens*** books are still outstanding and worth the small effort it needs to keep his sources running.

Comment: Should be noted: on line 60, change **size_t** to **socklen_t** ... silly mistake but I thought Jörg was referring to the variable name, not type!